# django refactoring models

Tags: django

I've been doing a little clean up on my django project and so I decided to rename some models remove some unnecessary fields etc.  I dropped all the tables from the dbase and reran "syncdb".  However, now I'm getting and error

```
Could not import pollsite.polls.views. Error was: cannot import name OldTableName
```

Its a template error from base.html

OldTableName doesn't exist anymore (I've renamed it).  Is there something else I need to run to get the admin site to work properly with the new schema?

Comment: Have you made sure all of your imports in all of your files have been updated to reflect the new name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your imports in your pollsite.polls.views. Most likely you still have an import of the old model name in that file.